# Lamsonproject - how to test the changes in the core?

Tags: python, email, smtp, lamson

I'm extending the core of [lamson server](http://lamsonproject.org/) because I need it. What I need is to test it whether I've do it right or wrong by sending the SMTP and ESTMP commands to it such as `HELO, EHLO` and others and retrieving a reply from it. It's hosted on localhost. In the documentation it doesn't say how to do that and I can't figure out how to do it.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually connect to the server instance using telnet.  Assuming it's connected to local port 25, from a *nix machine it may look similar to this:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 25

Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 ...banner from server...

ehlo localhost

250-...server... welcomes localhost
250-...other ehlo responses...
250 OK

quit

221 Bye
```

Windows command line works similarly.

[RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) covers the protocol.  There are also a few sample transactions in the appendix.

Once you have the server running well you can use a UI email client for more advanced testing.  Sometimes I use [Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/thunderbird) and configure it to deliver to 127.0.0.1.  This keeps my regular email client unmodified.

Comment: The question is rather how to run the server locally.

Comment: You said "What I need is to test it whether I've do it right or wrong by sending the SMTP and ESTMP commands to it such as HELO, EHLO..."  Did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp, in your question you are not asking how to **launch** it, you are asking how to **test** it.  This implies you are already launching it.  Please adjust your question to ask how to **launch** it.  Or, maybe accept my answer on how to **test** and ask a new question on how to **launch** it.

Comment: **Collect geolocated Twitter dataset using Python**, huh?